# How can I use Hugepage memory from kernel space?

Tags: memory, kernel-module, huge-pages

i need to be able to allocate 2MB or 4MB sized pages of memory in a kernel module.

Comment: What OS do you mean?

Comment: Linux (kernel 2.6.32)

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Kernel for allocation of continuous memory you can use function:

`__get_free_pages(flags, page_rate);`

where `flags` is usual flags and `page_rate` defines number of allocated pages where: number of pages = 2 ^ `page_rate`. You can use this function as proxy between the Kernel and your calling code.

Another approach is allocate huge page if it is possible.